# Multiple applications and shared containers with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to understand what would be the best approach here.

One server, multiple applications, some containers uses same image.

Example #1:

two `docker-compose.yml` files for each application

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ...

  app:
    image: app/one
    depends_on:
      - db
    ...
```

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ...

  app:
    image: app/two
    depends_on:
      - db
    ...
```

Example #2:

combine everything in one `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ...

  app1:
    image: app/one
    depends_on:
      - db
    ...

  app2:
    image: app/two
    depends_on:
      - db
    ...
```

Is there a common practice?

Comment: Can you explain more on the query? As per your compose file diff, instead of 2 DB containers, now you only have 1. Which option should you choose depends solely on your system design and requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that are common practice:

1. Check in a `docker-compose.yml` file with the application's source code (frequently at the root directory of the repository next to a `Dockerfile`)
2. Do not share databases between applications (containers make it very easy to start a second one)

Both of these things would suggest two separate `docker-compose.yml` files.

A single `docker-compose.yml` file could make sense in situations where you have multiple services that are cooperating so it doesn't make sense to launch one without the other.  (You have a REST API service, but it has an associated Nginx frontend and a specialized caching service that all go together, for example.)  Calling from one Docker Compose setup to another is slightly tricky and at small scale it can make sense to just put tightly connected things together.

At larger scale, it could also make sense to have a separate repository of just deployment specifications; this makes a little more sense with cluster managers like Kubernetes, and even then it's a style choice whether to have one repository with just deployment data, or to keep the deployment setup with the services.

Comment: Some applications didn't have `docker-compose.yml` file, just a docker image. So I had to write yml file myself. 
But my concern was that when I start multiple DB containers (also redis), that would leave me with multiple mysql processes and multiple volumes for the data. Couldn't find the answer if that's okay or not.
It's a "self-hosted go away from Google" type of thing.

Comment: Yes, running multiple databases with multiple volumes (one per service/application) is totally normal.

Comment: @DavidMaze Imagine i have two completely different projects that are not related to each other and i have two `docker-compose.yml`.  both projects use postgres database. should i connect these projects to one postgres container or each app has it's own postgres? i'm not sure what is going on in the background :\

Comment: Each application's `docker-compose.yml` declares all of its local container dependencies, and you do not share resources like databases between separate projects.  Running multiple databases in containers is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how related are app1 and app2 from each other.

From my point of view, an app is a set of tightly related things: one or more services, a database and a frontend. In that case, having them all together in the same docker compose is the way to do it.

In your case, if your app1 must use the same databases or tables as app2, then it is perfectly fine to have them in the same docker compose. In the other hand, if app1 and app2 uses different databases and do not interact with each other, then they are effectively separate and independent applications, so they should run on different docker compose configurations.